# How to access the MongoDB 'local' database in Cloud Foundy?

Tags: mongodb, cloud, cloud-foundry

When I create a binding with the service MongoDB, CF creates me a new user and provides me credentials/db name which cannot access the 'local' database as the user has not the admin role.

See below in the screenshot, I can access the 'local' database on my MongoDB installed locally on my PC and on the CF database (connected with SSH) I can only accesses the DB '201af166f4b82788' and I do not see the 'local'.

[image: local and CF MongoDB]

How could I grant access to the local DB to my CF user?

Thanks!

Comment: why you need to access `local` DB? What you wish to achieve? What's your CF provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your Mongodb provider does not give you the permissions to do this.  I don't think there's anything you can do to circumvent the permissions given by your provider.

If you have a legit use case that needs access, you should contact the Support team for your Mongodb provider and see if they can do anything to help.

Other options would be to find a different Mongodb provider, perhaps one that can provide you with a dedicated Mongodb server or host your own Mongodb.  If you host your own then you can configure it to do whatever you want.

If you end up hosting your own or using a provider that's outside of your Cloud Foundry marketplace, you can create a user provided service (see `cf cups`) with the information, bind that to your app and read the information just like you would from a provider in the marketplace.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel! I also think that this would be a dead end! I'll check another provider.